# Cannot update and delete With RHManagedObject library

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data

I'm not able to update or delete an object from Entity using RHManagedObject library. I can create a new object, do stuff with it and then commit. But when i try to update an object, it throws an error in RHManagedObject

```
-[NSManagedObject didUpdate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb8c3610
```

I have no idea what am i doing wrong. Take a look:

```
 Client *clientToInsert =[Client getWithPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"f_id=%@", self.clientToEdit.f_id] error:nil];
 clientToInsert.f_person = personName;
 clientToInsert.f_phone = phone;
 NSError *err = [Client commit];
```

Hope someone had the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you also using an entity subclass, as instructed on the RHManagedObject wiki page? In other words, do you have both ClientEntity and Client classes?

It seems to me like the entity in your data model is not Client and you haven't set the class to Client.

[image]

My guess is that in your case, the Class field says 'NSManagedObject'. Always make sure that Name is the the name of the entity (should be automatically) and that Class is the name of your class. The Class field can be left empty (in which case it'll say 'NSManagedObject') if the entity and your class have the same name.

I've been using RHManagedObject for several years now, it's a great library, but I've never bothered using those entity classes. I'd just name my entity Client and make an RHManagedObject subclass called Client as well. Those entity classes are only useful if you're going to add additional properties or methods to your RHManagedObject subclass.

Comment: I didn't even knew that this must be done. When i changed it, everything worked great. Thank you sir. You really saved me.